# Authenticating to Microsoft Graph using Microsoft.Identity.Client

Tags: c#, azure, office365

We're trying to implement an unattended C# application that automates some email activities - the app is supposed to authenticate on behalf of users with standard credentials (simple username and password), using **Microsoft.Identity.Client** library (4.47.2). Our environment requires that it is easy to setup and completely void of human interaction (thus we can't use integrated windows auth or other methods). After authentication and authorization, we're planning on using the Microsoft Graph nuget library to do the required graph calls (such as accessing mail folders, messages, etc.).

Our situation: we're trying to authenticate with a client app instance, using the **AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword** call, retrieve a token and create a GraphServiceClient object. We've managed to implement this and are able to fetch user details (such as email, name and so on) but when trying to access other graph aspects (such as MailFolders) we keep getting **ErrorAccessDenied**:

```
Code: ErrorAccessDenied
Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

Here is the code we're using:

```
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
string clientId = "app_client_id_from_azure_portal";
            
IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
   .Create(clientId)
   .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
   .Build();

string pwd = "my_password";
string username = "my_email";
SecureString pass = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd)
   pass.AppendChar(c);

AuthenticationResult res = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, pass).ExecuteAsync();

GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", 
   new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
{
   requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", res.AccessToken);
}));

var inbox = await client.Me.MailFolders["inbox"].Request().GetAsync();
```

Client ID is obtained from the Azure Portal, with the app that's registered. The username in question is part of the AD directory for this app and has the app authorized. Permissions for the app are also granted as described in the docs:

[image]

Can anyone shed some light into what we're doing wrong? We've been trying to get this working for over two weeks.

**Note**: I'm sure this is an authorization issue, since we're able to get user details but not access lower level components. Mainly with the token that's being issued, because if we copy/paste and hardcode the token we get from the Graph Explorer (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) everything works correctly and we're not getting the access denied error anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I registered one multi-tenant Azure AD application and added **API permissions** like below:

[image]

When I ran the **same code** as you by including user credentials, I got **same error** as below:

[image]

To know what **permissions** your access token has, print the token by adding below line in your code:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Token: " + res.AccessToken);
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, decode the above token in [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) and you can see permissions in **`scp`** claim like below:

[image]

The error usually occurs if access token does not have **required permissions** to list mail folders such as  *Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite*

You can also decode the token from **Graph Explorer** to know what permissions it has, by pasting the token in  [**jwt.ms**](https://jwt.ms/) .

To **resolve** the error, add at least one of the above **Delegated** permissions in your application:

[image]

When I ran the code again, I got the results successfully like below:

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
string clientId = "806d0e6f-03a7-4135-839e-969xxxxxxx8d2";

IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
   .Create(clientId)
   .WithAuthority(AadAuthorityAudience.AzureAdMultipleOrgs)
   .Build();

string pwd = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
string username = "admin@xxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
SecureString pass = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in pwd)
    pass.AppendChar(c);

AuthenticationResult res = await app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, username, pass).ExecuteAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Token: " + res.AccessToken);

GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
   new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
   {
       requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", res.AccessToken);
   }));

var inbox = await client.Me.MailFolders["inbox"].Request().GetAsync();

Console.WriteLine("\nID: " + inbox.Id);
Console.WriteLine("Folder Name: " + inbox.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine("Parent Folder ID: " + inbox.ParentFolderId);
Console.WriteLine("Total Messages Count: " + inbox.TotalItemCount);
Console.WriteLine("Unread Messages Count: " + inbox.UnreadItemCount);
```

**Output:**

[image]

When I decoded the above token, it contains **`Mail.Read`** and **`Mail.ReadBasic`** permissions like below:

[image]

To fetch **user details** such as email, name etc., **`User.Read`** Delegated permission is enough but for listing mail folders, you need extra permissions.

In your case, make sure to grant at least one of the **Delegated** permissions like *Mail.Read, Mail.ReadBasic, Mail.ReadWrite*

Comment: first of all I would like to personally thank you for the effort. The time you took to replicate this issue and carefully format your answer is amazing. The world needs more people like you.

Though I haven't managed to fix this, I think I'm on the right path. After adding the required API permissions, I'm inspecting the token with jwt.ms, but it seems the permissions are not updated, even though they're set in Azure - I keep getting "scp": "openid profile User.Read email".

Could this be caused by the fact the app is multi-tenant and unverified?

Comment: Not sure why it's not reflecting for you in `scp` claim even after adding them in application. Even my application is multitenant and I'm not facing any issue.

Comment: After adding the required permissions, have you generated the token again?

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, a new token is generated with each run by the AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword call, so yes. What's strange is that if I force the scopes to var scopes = new[] { "MailboxSettings.ReadWrite", "User.Read", "profile", "openid", "email", "Mail.Read", "Mail.ReadBasic" }; and try to do an interactive login, I get the message that the app is unverified and needs admin approval.

Comment: Do you have Global Admin role and did you grant admin consent to those permissions?

Comment: Yes, I'm the global admin - but the email I'm trying to get the token for is part of my AD org, but is external. I've also admin consented to all permissions (even though from my understanding it's not required for delegated perms).

Mind you, I only seem to be able to get the prompt with Need Admin Approval if I'm using an interactive login. Which should be required, as otherwise I get "'AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application"

Comment: Username password flow is not supported for guest users that are invited to Azure AD tenant. Check this [MsDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc#:~:text=Personal%20accounts%20that%20are%20invited%20to%20an%20Azure%20AD%20tenant%20can%27t%20use%20the%20ROPC%20flow)

Comment: I'm familiar with the link from the initial reading. I was expecting it wasn't the case here, because I can correctly get a token and access basic user information - so I was assuming it was working in my case as well...

In any case, thank you very much for all your effort, I will be marking your answer as the correct one. Cheers!